# how to build two versions with webdev build?

Tags: dart, dart2js

is it possible to compile two versions when building?

I would like to have a build/ which is the production release for end users and a buildDev/ with less restrictive dart2js flags. Something like that.

The idea is to be able to access a page with some security token that forces the page use the dart2js debug version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to do in a single build command. `webdev build --no-release` will use the `dev_options` instead of `release_options`, so to get both flavors of build you'll need to run two commands, `webdev build; webdev build --no-release -o buildDev`.

Comment: yeah, that is what I am ending up doing.